# permute both rols and cols of one matrix to best approximate another?

Tags: co.combinatorics

I've got two square real matrices ($A$ and $B$) and I want to find a permutation of the rows and columns (same permutation) to best approximate the other matrix. E.g. with $P$ as a permutation matrix and say the Frobenius norm

$\min_{P \in \Pi} || A - PBP^T ||_F$

Now, I know (a) if $A = PBP^T$ then you can find $P$ through the eigenvalue decompositions since the eigenvectors of $B$ are permuted eigenvectors of $A$ and (b) if you only permute the rows (or cols), i.e. $\min_P ||A - PB||_F$ this is a linear assignment problem and can easily be solved.

Can anyone help by identifying what the problem is? I figure it must be well known but I haven't seen it yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem looks like the [famous Quadratic assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_assignment_problem), which means that in general you are out of luck as far as an exact solution is concerned.

Comment: I've just been reading about QAP now and it does indeed appear that the simultaneous permutation makes it quadratic. Does it help any if both $a_{ij}$ and $b_{ij} \in \\{0,1\\}$?

Comment: oops, I mean $a_{ij}$ and $b_{ij}$ in {0,1}

Comment: I don't that the restriction to boolean matrices will make things easier....the literature on QAP's definitely contains a discussion of such special cases.

Comment: In particular, the graph isomorphism problem is a sub-case of the $\\{0,1\\}$ case.